# Does blademail return damage from cleave?

Tags: dota

The question says it all but here's a scenario:

Does Sven's cleave damage will return to him if a hero within the range of cleave uses a blade mail? What if all the heroes uses blade mail and with the range of the cleave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**,blademail returns cleave damage since it is physical damage.

Even if somehow cleave ended being magic damage it would still be returned by blademail since it returns physical and magic damage(with exception on HP removal spells and pure damage spells).

Comment: If all enemy heroes are wearing blademail and within the range of cleave you get all that damage returned. So in this rare occasion your in for a world of hurt.

Comment: So, does this means that the stat removal (3rd skill) of Slark cannot be returned by blademail?

Comment: yes,stats removal in this case strength works as HP removal so it is ignored by blademail.Bud the damage from the physical attack itself is reflected normally.